# NSMutableArray (plist) show UIImage on specific dictionaries

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsmutablearray, plist

I'm making an app that has some questions, and those questions are stored in an NSMutableArray inside a plist.

[image: plist]

My question is, I wanted to add some harder questions and put an UIImage on those specific questions(dictionaries). How can I do it? Should I just create a BOOL value? How? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have single image for all your harder questions then you can use some boolean flag indicating that question needs an image (lets say with *"hard"* key). In code it will look something like:

```
if ([[questionDict objectForKey:@"hard"] boolValue]) {
   // Question needs image, display it appropriately
}
```

If you plan to have different images for different questions then you can add string value for image path to your plist. In code it will be:

```
NSString *imagePath = [questionDict objectForKey:@"imagePath"];
if (imagePath) {
// Question needs image, display it appropriately using imagePath
}
```

Note that for questions that do not have images you do not need to add fields in plist file - in that case `objectForKey:` will return nil and code in if clause will not be executed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is the "questionDict"? I tough it was the array, but I added if ([[self.questionsAndAnswersArray objectForKey:@"hard"] booleanValue]) and it says "no visible @interface for 'nsmutablearray' declares the selector 'objectForKey' !

Comment: questionDict is a dictionary you store in array, i.e. you need to get particular question first: NSDictionary* questionDict = self.questionsAndAnswersArray[0];

Comment: my dictionaries are the questions itself...I now tried  NSDictionary* questionDict = self.questionsAndAnswersArray;
   
    if ([[questionDict objectForKey:@"hard"] booleanValue]) {
        NSLog(@"Hard"); but it now says "No known instance method for selector 'booleanValue'. Thanks for your help!

Comment: As I told - your array contains questions, which in fact will have NSDictionary type. You get particular question(dictionary) by its index (e.g. self.questionsAndAnswersArray[0]) and work with it

Comment: I tried it and it will only let me if I change booleanValue for boolValue but it does not work (I'm testing with NSLog). Is there at least a way I can select one picture and say that if that question is appearing the image is not hidden? Or something like that? This is so important...please help me, I'm kind of noob when it comes to NSArrays and specially NSDictionaries. Thanks!

Comment: boolValue is correct method indeed. It should work, have you added field with that bool value to any question in your plist?

Comment: Yes, I added a Boolean Value to the question I want, with the key hard and value = YES. It is working but now when it should. Sometimes the image shows up (when it's not supposed to) and when it's supposed to show up it does not. Could it be because of my shuffle method?

Comment: Isn't there a simpler way to do it? something like if (questionLabel.text=@"..."), something that works easily? please...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40952/discussion-between-vladimir-and-mykod)